# jqplot multiple array as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, jqplot

Hi I'm using a `servlet` response to supply parameter to `jqplot` for a `barchart`

the `servlet` response statement is something like this:

```
out.println("725,759,2032,171,2761,133175,166163,409,28630,3754@0,375,1482,0,2051,125857,167524,0,125406,4022@0,0,0,1,0,125406,0,0,0,0");
```

If it is a success response, `ajax` will then call a plot function using `dataRenderer: dataRenderer(dataArr)` as the array parameter. 
However, an **error indicate "No data specified" is found**.

I try to log the dataRenderer return which is

```
"725,759,2032,171,2761,133175,166163,409,28630,3754,0,375,1482,0,2051,125857,167524,0,125406,4022,0,0,0,1,0,125406,0,0,0,0"
```

But the expected answer should be

```
[725,759,2032,171,2761,133175,166163,409,28630,3754],[0,375,1482,0,2051,125857,167524,0,125406,4022],[0,0,0,1,0,125406,0,0,0,0]
```

Any help is highly appreciated! thanks

```
function log(msg) {
setTimeout(function() {
    throw new Error(msg);
}, 0);
}

var form = $('#form1');
var storedData = [3, 7];
var plot1;

//$( "#plot" ).click(function(){
form.submit(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: form.attr('method'),
 url: form.attr('action'),
 data: {n1:n1.value,n2:n2.value},
 success: function (data) {
 var result=data;
 //$('#result').attr("value",result);
 renderGraph(result);
 }
 });
 return false;
 });


 var dataRenderer = function(userData){

    var result = new Array();


    var seperator1 = /\s*@\s*/;
    var seperator2 = /\s*,\s*/;

    storedData = userData.split(seperator1);
    result.push(storedData[0].split(seperator2));
    result.push(storedData[1].split(seperator2));
    result.push(storedData[2].split(seperator2));

    return result;
 };

 function renderGraph(dataArr) {

if (plot1) {
    plot1.destroy();

}


 log(dataRenderer(dataArr));



var ticks = ['Pub1', 'Pub101', 'Pub121', 'Pub141', 'Pub161', 'Pub2', 'Pub3', 'Pub61', 'Pub81', 'Pub82'];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [], {

                    dataRenderer: dataRenderer(dataArr),
        seriesColors : ['#1cbd17', '#e44e23', '#23b9e4', '#C7754C', '#17BDB8', '#b817bd'],
        seriesDefaults : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
                fillToZero : true
            }
        },
        series : [{
                label : 'delivered'
            }, {
                label : 'filtered out'
            }, {
                label : 'incomplete'
            }, {
                label : ''
            }
        ],
        legend : {
            show : true,
            placement : 'outsideGrid'
        },
        axes : {
            xaxis : {
                renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks : ticks
            },
            yaxis : {
                pad : 1.05,
                tickOptions : {
                    formatString : '%d'
                }
            }
        }

    });  

    plot1.resetAxesScale(); 
    plot1.replot();
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, solved!!! jqplot suppose to take a int array , while i was supplying a str array.
That's why i got an error .

here are the fix :

```
        result.push(storedData[0].split(seperator2).map(Number));
        result.push(storedData[1].split(seperator2).map(Number));
        result.push(storedData[2].split(seperator2).map(Number));
```

Hope this helps if someone else got the same problem.